# Get records which field contains specific digits

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Having some field in table that could contain between either 1, 2 or 3 digits separated by commas. So as follows example below:

```
ID | digitField
1  |   4, 55
2  |   1 ,70,33
3  |   8 
4  |   9,22,43
5  |   1,833,3
6  |   77,9
7  |   33
8  |   2,3335
9  |   6, 33
```

Now having some digit i would like to search and get ID of the records which containing it. What will be the best approach to search for those records?

For instance i am seeking for every occurrence of digit 33. In this case i would like to get those records based on above example:

```
2  |   1,70,33
7  |   33
9  |   6, 33
```

Does following query would be good enough and not risky to get wrong results, or could you give better solution?:

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(digitField, '33');
```

This query is very important as result ids will delete shop products so i would like to avoid wrong results. **Note that in our case records containing 3, 833 or 3335 cannot match as we looking for 33. Note also that the could be some spaces between within that field (that's something which is already implemented and have no chance to change it)**

Looking for best solution.

Additional question to correctly close up query within string:

```
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(strcon)
cnn.Open()
'--Just in case remove all spaces from string in field Materials before
Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(";WITH yourtable as ( SELECT ID, REPLACE(digitField, ' ', '') digitfield FROM tempDigit ) 
                        SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE digitField = @matId
                        OR digitField LIKE @matId+',%'
                        OR digitField LIKE '%,'+@matId
                        OR digitField LIKE '%,'+@matId+',%'", cnn)
    dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@matId", matId.ToString))
    dad.Fill(dt)
    If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        result = dt
    End If
End Using
cnn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Do you have a Full Text Index on the column `digitField`? Otherwise you cannot use [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Comment: In case if you have `ID 3` as `8333`, this also need to return in the result?

Comment: No - only exact number in this case 33 so not 3 but if i would 3 then 33 cannot be returned

Comment: no i do not have index on it, should i by the way?

Comment: index on digitField column will likely not be used for `LIKE` comparision, but it will be an optimization anyway because sql-server should not access table and should look only into index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter all possible variations of given number's occurences. 
If field can contains spaces - just remove them.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(digitField, ' ', '') AS pureField) digit
WHERE digit.pureField = @Exact        --if only one number in field
   OR digit.pureField LIKE @Begin   --if number in the beginning of text
   OR digit.pureField LIKE @End   --if number in the end of text
   OR digit.pureField LIKE @Middle --if number in the middle of text
```

Sql parameters creating

```vb
Dim parameters As SqlParameter() = 
{
    New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Exact", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = matId.ToString()},
    New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Begin", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = $"{matId},%"},
    New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@End", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = $"%,{matId}"},
    New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Middle", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = $"%,{matId},%"},
}
```

Comment: note that also their could be spaces between - this is something already implemented...

Comment: @JimmyJimm, remove the spaces before comparing data.

Comment: I like your answer but still thinking whether there is still no mistake or something that could return wrong result. Are you sure that this will be working as it should on every situation according to what i wrote in mian post?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it will work. You can easily test queries with all possible data variation you have.

Comment: you should use CTE instead of CROSS APPLY, also you should use binary collation to speedup things

Comment: @MtwStark what's the diffrence and why?

Comment: @JimmyJimm in this case, I think there is no difference, because the optimizer understand the simple query, but CROSS APPLY "could" be executed for each "parent" record, so use it carefully or can bring to performances issues

Comment: @MtwStart however is it better then to use your version?

Comment: @MtwStark, sorry didn't see any problem `CROSS APPLY` can bring in this case. If OP need to execute this query often, then he can consider using of persisted `Computed Column`.

Comment: guys so which one yu advice to use either cross aply or cte version?

Comment: in this case CROSS APPLY is the same, because optimizer is smart enough. I was just saying that in this case you don't need it.

Comment: @JimmyJimm - it is your decision :)

Comment: i decided to take CTE version hope good choice right? If you so kind can you also help me to put those query into string - something is wrong there - can you look at main post to avoid additional topic please.

Comment: @JimmyJimm a great improvement to this query is to use binary collation for `LIKE` comparision. `OR digitField collate Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '33,%' collate Latin1_General_BIN` is much faster than `OR digitField LIKE '33,%'`

Comment: @MtwStart - i leave it as it is now - can you help to put it inside string correctly? i have problems with it whats wrong (please check my main post) something is wrong there

Comment: @JimmyJimm you have to change `'@matId,%'` with `@matid+',%'` and so on in each `LIKE`, I would also strip off comments.. and finally if you need only column `ID`, change `SELECT *` with `SELECT ID`

Comment: @MtwStark about parameter as matId is comming as integer but field is varchar type should i also use ToString like this on parameter or not?:  dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@matId", matId.ToString))

Comment: @JimmyJimm, you can create all four parameters explicitly before query execution. Using parameters will sure that same already compiled query plan will be used.

Comment: @JimmyJimm `@matId` is numeric but `LIKE` works with strings, so you have two options, the 1st to pass it as numeric and convert it in your query, (so you have to change each `@matId` in `CAST(@matId as VARCHAR(10))` ), the 2nd options is to pass it as a string as you have said.

Comment: @MtwStark i modifed query again is it ok now?

Comment: @MtwStark, can you explain please why `With` will be better approach against `CROSS APPLY` in the query OP uses?

Comment: as I said before, _in this case CROSS APPLY is exactly the same_  What I meant was that in this case, the need is to calculate the column **before** the comparision. For this pourpose you can change each occurence of  `digitField` with `REPLACE(digitField, ' ', '')` in your query or (for readability) use the `;WITH` syntax. CROSS APPLY is designed for other pourposes, it should be used to execute a subquery for each row of the left table. (I have used it in my answer, take a look). however it is only my opinion.. (solo per intenderci.. è come sparare a una zanzara con un cannone.. ;) )

Comment: If you change each occurence of `digitField with REPLACE(digitField, ' ', '')`, then `REPLACE` method wil be executed four times. `CROSS APPLY` do exactly what it purpose is - execute `REPLACE` only once per row. In this case approach with `WITH` you will run two queries

Comment: `REPLACE(digitField, ' ', '')` will be calculated only once and reused 4 times. this is the fastest syntax. The same with CTE but with a little overhead. Theoretically CROSS APPLY will run as many queries as rows in the main table (1000 products = 1000 queries), but in this case optimizer understands what you want, and will not.

Comment: @MtwStark to be honest i am bit lost so does it mean ;WITH is better approach or bad approach?

Comment: @JimmyJimm do not worry. Your query is good and simple enough for you. More experienced SQL programmers (like me and @Fabio) will argue about how things works and which is the pros and the cons of each approach. There is not only one solution, there are many ways to reach a result, you should choice (or build) your own solution tied on you and your world. What I mean is that you will also have to mantain this query, so _in your case_, it is better to have a very simple query that runs in 500ms (good enough) than a unreadable, hard to understand, equivalent query that runs in 200ms (faster).

Comment: @MtwStark thx very much i will stay with version of Fabio but with the change of you said with ;WITH as i posted in main post. By the wasy can you look at my last question in that topic:? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890339/get-records-which-field-contains-specific-digits

Comment: @JimmyJimm which question?

Comment: @MtwStark here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890339/get-records-which-field-contains-specific-digits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120701/discussion-between-mtwstark-and-jimmyjimm).

Answer (score 1):

you need a table valued **SPLIT** function to "unpivot" your `digitField` into records, so

```
ID | digitField
1  |   4, 55
2  |   1 ,70,33
3  |   8
```

will become

```
ID | n  | digitField
1  | 1  | 4
1  | 2  | 55
2  | 1  | 1
2  | 2  | 70
2  | 3  | 33
3  | 1  | 8
```

then you will search for your number into this result.

There are many split functions around, you can google for them.
I have developed mine by myself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SPLIT]
/*
  MTW - FN_SPLIT()
  mtw@inbox.lv
*/
(
    @Line varchar(8000),
    @SplitOn varchar(10) = ','
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, -- VERY USEFUL TO MAKE JOINS AND TO CREATE THE UNIQUE INDEX ON SPLITTED STRINGS
    Data varchar(800) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (DATA, ID) -- THIS WILL MAKE REALLY FASTER THE QUERIES USING THIS FUNCTION
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Line IS NULL RETURN

    DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn+'X')-1 -- TO CATCH TRAILING SPACES PROBLEM WITH LEN()
    DECLARE @line_len INT = LEN(@line+'X')-1
    DECLARE @start_at INT = 1
    DECLARE @end_at INT
    DECLARE @data_len INT

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        IF @start_at > @line_len BREAK;
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @Line, @start_at)
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN @line_len ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) VALUES( SUBSTRING(@Line,@start_at,@data_len));
        SET @start_at = @start_at + @data_len + @split_on_len
    END

    RETURN
END
```

so your query will be:

```
;WITH
S AS (
    SELECT T.ID, X.Id N, RTRIM(LTRIM(X.Data)) digitField
    FROM T
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT *
        FROM FN_SPLIT(T.digitField, ',') F
    ) X
)
SELECT *
FROM S
WHERE digitField = '33'
ORDER BY 1,2
```

the result is:

```
ID  N   digitField
2   3   33
7   1   33
9   2   33
```

where column `N` is the position of your number in the original digitField column

Comment: thx for your time but its very long, what do you think about @Fabio answer will it fit requirments - i asked because its very short. I also test yours as well.

Comment: it is not so long.. the function fn_split, you have to run it once.. and it become "library" in your database. the query is short and clear and give also information about position. @Fabio solutions do the trick as well, but I would like to see performances on large product tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186323.aspx) you can get the matching result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CHARINDEX('33', digitField) >= 1;
```

Sample execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID INT, digitField VARCHAR (200));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (ID, digitField) VALUES
(1, '4, 55'),
(2, '1,70,33'),
(3, '8'), 
(4, '9,22,43'),
(5, '1,2,3'),
(6, '77,9'),
(7, '33'),
(8, '2,5'),
(9, '6, 33');

SELECT *
FROM @TestTable
WHERE CHARINDEX('33', digitField) >= 1;
```

Output:

```
ID  digitField
--------------
2   1,70,33
7   33
9   6, 33
```

Comment: do you think its so secure i cannot get result using it? As i mentioned its very important query as based on that i will be removing products from database.

Comment: This will pull the entries like `330` and `833` too. Need to fine-tune the query.

Comment: it should not put 330 and 833 but in this case 33 we looking only for 33